# Find out if WPF windows has been already loaded (Loaded event fired already)

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to find out whether WPF Window is loaded?
I have a method which accepts a window and hooks 'Loaded' event to it.
If window is already loaded, the event will not fire.
Is it possible to know this when accepting the argument?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have IsLoaded property of Window